# What does this regexp mean?

Tags: regex

So, what does next regexp actually mean?

```
str_([^_]*)(_[_0-9a-z]*)?
```

And is it equal to `^str_[^_]*(_[_0-9a-z]*)?`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.roblocher.com/technotes/regexp.aspx), might be useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str_` matches these characters literally

`([^_]*)` matches any character 0 or more times that is not a underscore

`(_[_0-9a-z]*)?` matches another underscore and then 0 or more of the characters `_0-9a-z`. This last part is optional.

[I wrote recently a really brief regex introduction, hope it will help you.](https://xisb.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/what-absolutely-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/).

Comment: so, let's say 'str_MOTH_clone' should match the regexp, right?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments to my answer, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ explains everything about a regular expression if you put it in.

```
str_([^_]*)(_[_0-9a-z]*)?
\  /^\  /^^^^\       /^^^
 \/ | \/ |||| \     / |||
 |  | |  ||||  \   /  ||`- Previous group is optional
 |  | |  ||||   \ /   |`-- End second capture group (an underscore and any amount of characters _, 0-9 or a-z)
 |  | |  ||||    |    `--- Match any amount (0-infinite) of previous (any character _, 0-9 or a-z)
 |  | |  ||||    `-------- Match any of the characters inside brackets
 |  | |  ||||              (0-9 means any number between 0 and 9, a-z means any lower case char between a and z)
 |  | |  |||`------------- Match "_" literally
 |  | |  ||`-------------- Start second capture group
 |  | |  |`--------------- End first capture group (any amount of any character which is not underscore)
 |  | |  `---------------- Match any amount (0-infinite) of previous (any character which is not underscore)
 |  | `------------------- ^ at the start inside [] means match any character not after ^
 |  |                      (In this case, match any which is not underscore)
 |  `--------------------- Start first capture group
 `------------------------ Match "str_" literally
```

The `^` at the start of `^str_[^_]*(_[_0-9a-z]*)?` just means that it should only match at the start of line of anything you input.

Comment: Whoah. Is this generated by a tool, or did you actually type that?

Comment: @li-aung-yip: Typed it, but I guess a tool for this would be a good idea. Thanks for the idea. :D

Comment: Upvote for sheer balls and effort. Next time, though, use regexr. ;)

Comment: @li-aung-yip: Heh, regexr does exactly that, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

`str_([^_]*)(_[_0-9a-z]*)?`

so, let's talk on regexp:

1) `([^_]*)` - catch `()` in any count(zero is possible) `*` symbols `[]`, that are not `^` this symbol `_`.

2) `(_[_0-9a-z]*)?` - to be or not to be `?` and catch `()` sequence with beginning symbol `_` and tail of sequence in which appear in any count `*` any symbol from set `[]` like `_` `a,b,c,..,z` or `0,1,..9`